# Laravel 9 Registered Users Cannot login

Tags: laravel, authentication, phpmyadmin, laravel-authentication, laravel-9

In my laravel 9 project, I made authentication process using laravel/ui dependecies. All user that has registered using localhost:8000/register are succesfully login to application. But those users that I inserted directly in phpMyAdmin are cannot login. The error always say *"These credentials do not match our records."* though the data is there in the users' table.

Do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: _those users that I inserted directly in phpMyAdmin cannot login_ have you hashed those records password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maulik is right, however it does not answer your question, since you are inserting records *directly* into PhpMyAdmin.

If you've used the `AuthController` that comes with Laravel then the password are hashed using Bcrypt. Check out this generator: [Bcrypt gen](https://bcrypt-generator.com/). Encrypt your string, plug that into PhpMyAdmin and try to login using the password you supplied before encrypting. Should work.

Comment: I spent 1 day in this thanks for you answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to create hashed password for it work!

```
$password = Hash::make('12345678');
```

above line will create hashed password, put it into password field

I hope it will work